# How to display text dynamically in svg

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have written the below code. 
In the code where we append text to the text variable, function inside text is not getting called as the label is having the same name. However I want to change the text output on click of each button.

Example: 1st on click of  button '2004', in pie chart text is displayed as Roger Federer (45%) ,Marat Safin (32%) and 23%. (Keys- Roger Federer, Marat Safin, empty)
second click on 2005 button, in pie chart, text is displayed as Marat Safin (32%), 23% and Lleyton Hewitt (34%). (Keys - Marat Safin, Lleyton Hewitt and empty) .. But i want it to display as Marat Safin (39%), Lleyton Hewitt (34%), 27% . Its not working according to logic as i wrote.

Please help!

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

path.slice {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

polyline {
    opacity: .3;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}
</style>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <button onclick="validate(2004);">2004</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2005);">2005</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2006);">2006</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2007);">2007</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2008);">2008</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2009);">2009</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2010);">2010</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2011);">2011</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2012);">2012</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2013);">2013</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2014);">2014</button>
</div>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 960,
    height = 450,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ 
    //alert(d.data.label);
    return d.data.label; };

var c04 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Roger Federer", "Marat Safin","empty"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#ff8c00","#18F8FC"]);
var c05 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Marat Safin", "Lleyton Hewitt"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#ff8c00", "#6b486b"]);
var c06 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Marcos Baghdatis", "Roger Federer","empty"])
    .range(["#a05d56", "#98abc5","#18F8FC"]);
var c07 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Roger Federer", "Fernando Gonzalez"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#98abc5", "#d0743c"]);
var c08 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Novak Djokovic", "Jo-Wilfried Tsonga","empty"])
    .range(["#7b6888", "#3E1BEE","#18F8FC"]);
var c09 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Rafael Nadal", "Roger Federer"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#000000", "#98abc5"]);
var c10 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Roger Federer", "Andy Murray","empty"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#FFFF00","#18F8FC"]);
var c11 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Andy Murray", "Novak Djokovic"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#FFFF00", "#7b6888"]);
var c12 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Novak Djokovic", "Rafael Nadal","empty"])
    .range(["#7b6888", "#000000","#18F8FC"]);
var c13 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Andy Murray", "Novak Djokovic"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#FFFF00", "#7b6888"]);
var c14 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Rafael Nadal", "Stanislas Wawrinka","empty"])
    .range(["#000000", "#3BEE1B","#18F8FC"]);


function Year (year){ //alert(year);
    if(year== '2004'){
        var labels = c04.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 45 }
            if(label == 'Marat Safin')
                return { label: label, value: 32 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 23 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2005'){
        var labels = c05.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Marat Safin')
            return { label: label, value: 39 }
            if(label == 'Lleyton Hewitt')
                return { label: label, value: 34 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 27 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2006'){
        var labels = c06.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 46 }
            if(label == 'Marcos Baghdatis')
                return { label: label, value: 38 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 31 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2007'){
        var labels = c07.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 40 }
            if(label == 'Fernando Gonzalez')
                return { label: label, value: 20 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 40 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2008'){
        var labels = c08.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
            return { label: label, value: 36 }
            if(label == 'Jo-Wilfried Tsonga')
                return { label: label, value: 29 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 35 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2009'){
        var labels = c09.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Rafael Nadal')
            return { label: label, value: 40 }
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
                return { label: label, value: 41 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 19 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2010'){
        var labels = c10.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 37 }
            if(label == 'Andy Murray')
                return { label: label, value: 32 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 31 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2011'){
        var labels = c11.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Andy Murray')
            return { label: label, value: 33 }
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
                return { label: label, value: 51 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 16 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2012'){
        var labels = c12.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
            return { label: label, value: 41 }
            if(label == 'Rafael Nadal')
                return { label: label, value: 34 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 25 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2013'){
        var labels = c13.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
            return { label: label, value: 33 }
            if(label == 'Andy Murray')
                return { label: label, value: 28 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 39 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2014'){
        var labels = c14.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Rafael Nadal')
            return { label: label, value: 29 }
            if(label == 'Stanislas Wawrinka')
                return { label: label, value: 44 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 27 }
        });
    }
}
var text ;
var globalYear = '';
function validate(year){

    globalYear = year;
    change(Year(year));
}

function change(data) {

    /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            if(globalYear=='2004')
                return c04(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2005')
                return c05(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2006')
                return c06(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2007')
                return c07(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2008')
                return c08(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2009')
                return c09(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2010')
                return c10(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2011')
                return c11(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2012')
                return c12(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2013')
                return c13(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2014')
                return c14(d.data.label);
        })
        .attr("class", "slice");

    slice       
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })


    slice.exit().remove();

    /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

    //text.remove();
    text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { //alert(d.data.label);      

            if(globalYear=='2004'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2005'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (39%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Lleyton Hewitt'){
                    return 'Lleyton Hewitt (34%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '27%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2006'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2007'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2008'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2009'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2010'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2011'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2012'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2013'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2014'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
        });

    function midAngle(d){
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
    }

    text.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        });

    text.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    polyline.enter()
        .append("polyline");

    polyline.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("points", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
            };          
        });

    polyline.exit()
        .remove();
};

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried making a fiddle: pls try repairing it
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/358nnygq/)

Comment: I am able to open in any browser properly, but its not working in fiddle @Joniras

Comment: Press 'F12' then go to console to check errors, fix them then we'll see whats up :)

Answer (score -1):

Working updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/358nnygq/5/

Needed to comment out the alerts to show transitions

HTML

```
<body>
<div align="center">
    <button onclick="validate(2004);">2004</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2005);">2005</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2006);">2006</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2007);">2007</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2008);">2008</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2009);">2009</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2010);">2010</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2011);">2011</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2012);">2012</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2013);">2013</button>
    <button onclick="validate(2014);">2014</button>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

path.slice {
    stroke-width: 2px;
}

polyline {
    opacity: .3;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
}
```

JS

```
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 960,
    height = 450,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ 
    //alert(d.data.label);
    return d.data.label; };

var c04 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Roger Federer", "Marat Safin","empty"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#ff8c00","#18F8FC"]);
var c05 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Marat Safin", "Lleyton Hewitt"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#ff8c00", "#6b486b"]);
var c06 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Marcos Baghdatis", "Roger Federer","empty"])
    .range(["#a05d56", "#98abc5","#18F8FC"]);
var c07 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Roger Federer", "Fernando Gonzalez"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#98abc5", "#d0743c"]);
var c08 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Novak Djokovic", "Jo-Wilfried Tsonga","empty"])
    .range(["#7b6888", "#3E1BEE","#18F8FC"]);
var c09 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Rafael Nadal", "Roger Federer"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#000000", "#98abc5"]);
var c10 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Roger Federer", "Andy Murray","empty"])
    .range(["#98abc5", "#FFFF00","#18F8FC"]);
var c11 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Andy Murray", "Novak Djokovic"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#FFFF00", "#7b6888"]);
var c12 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Novak Djokovic", "Rafael Nadal","empty"])
    .range(["#7b6888", "#000000","#18F8FC"]);
var c13 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["empty","Andy Murray", "Novak Djokovic"])
    .range(["#18F8FC","#FFFF00", "#7b6888"]);
var c14 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["Rafael Nadal", "Stanislas Wawrinka","empty"])
    .range(["#000000", "#3BEE1B","#18F8FC"]);


function Year (year){ //alert(year);
    if(year== '2004'){
        var labels = c04.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 45 }
            if(label == 'Marat Safin')
                return { label: label, value: 32 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 23 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2005'){
        var labels = c05.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Marat Safin')
            return { label: label, value: 39 }
            if(label == 'Lleyton Hewitt')
                return { label: label, value: 34 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 27 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2006'){
        var labels = c06.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 46 }
            if(label == 'Marcos Baghdatis')
                return { label: label, value: 38 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 31 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2007'){
        var labels = c07.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 40 }
            if(label == 'Fernando Gonzalez')
                return { label: label, value: 20 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 40 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2008'){
        var labels = c08.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
            return { label: label, value: 36 }
            if(label == 'Jo-Wilfried Tsonga')
                return { label: label, value: 29 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 35 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2009'){
        var labels = c09.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Rafael Nadal')
            return { label: label, value: 40 }
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
                return { label: label, value: 41 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 19 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2010'){
        var labels = c10.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Roger Federer')
            return { label: label, value: 37 }
            if(label == 'Andy Murray')
                return { label: label, value: 32 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 31 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2011'){
        var labels = c11.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Andy Murray')
            return { label: label, value: 33 }
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
                return { label: label, value: 51 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 16 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2012'){
        var labels = c12.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
            return { label: label, value: 41 }
            if(label == 'Rafael Nadal')
                return { label: label, value: 34 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 25 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2013'){
        var labels = c13.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Novak Djokovic')
            return { label: label, value: 33 }
            if(label == 'Andy Murray')
                return { label: label, value: 28 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 39 }
        });
    }
    if(year== '2014'){
        var labels = c14.domain();
        return labels.map(function(label){
            if(label == 'Rafael Nadal')
            return { label: label, value: 29 }
            if(label == 'Stanislas Wawrinka')
                return { label: label, value: 44 }
            if(label == 'empty')
                return { label: label, value: 27 }
        });
    }
}
var text ;
var globalYear = '';
function validate(year){

    globalYear = year;
    change(Year(year));
}

function change(data) {

    /* ------- PIE SLICES -------*/
    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(data), key);
    var x = 0, y =0;
    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .style("fill", function(d) { 
            if(globalYear=='2004')
                return c04(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2005')
                return c05(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2006')
                return c06(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2007')
                return c07(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2008')
                return c08(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2009')
                return c09(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2010')
                return c10(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2011')
                return c11(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2012')
                return c12(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2013')
                return c13(d.data.label);
            if(globalYear=='2014')
                return c14(d.data.label);
        })
        .attr("class", "slice");

    slice       
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
           // alert(d.data.label);
            //putText();
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                return arc(interpolate(t));
            };
        })

    slice.exit().remove();

    /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

    //text.remove();
    text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { //alert(d.data.label);      

            if(globalYear=='2004'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2005'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (39%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Lleyton Hewitt'){
                    return 'Lleyton Hewitt (34%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '27%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2006'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2007'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2008'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2009'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2010'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2011'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2012'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2013'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
            if(globalYear=='2014'){
                if(d.data.label == 'Roger Federer'){
                    return 'Roger Federer (45%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'Marat Safin'){
                    return 'Marat Safin (32%)';
                }else if(d.data.label == 'empty'){
                    return '23%';
                }
            }
        });

    function midAngle(d){
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
    }

    text.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        });

    text.exit()
        .remove();

    /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    polyline.enter()
        .append("polyline");

    polyline.transition().duration(1000)
        .attrTween("points", function(d){
            this._current = this._current || d;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
            };          
        });

    polyline.exit()
        .remove();
};
```

Comment: Any luck on the required output @AJ_91